# Pass Func<Task> as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have a method:

```
public async Task Method(Func<Task> action)
```

This function basically checks if few seconds have passed since the last run time.

I tried:

```
Func<Task> timer = async () => { await Task.Delay(3000);};
```

and invoking it like that

```
Func<Task> check = await _className.Method(timer);
```

However it says

> Cannot implicitly convert 'void' to 'System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'

Basically I am not able to pass a delayed task to a function.

Comment: What's `check`? The delegate you've created is called `timer`. I recommend you make this a [mre].

Comment: Not real code. Comma is missing in `timer`.

Comment: Don't do `Func<Task> timer = async () => { await Task.Delay(3000);};`, just do `Func<Task> timer = () => Task.Delay(3000);`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trivial example of calling Method with a `Func<Task>`.

```
Func<Task> timer = async () => { await Task.Delay(3000);};

await Method(timer);


async Task Method(Func<Task> action)
{
   await action();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but this code works:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Func<Task> timer = async () => { await Task.Delay(3000); };
        var theTask = Method(timer);
        await theTask;
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // ~3000
    }

    public static async Task Method(Func<Task> action)
    {
        await action();
    }
}
```

I just put in `var theTask = Method(timer);` to illustrate that you can assign the return value to a `Task` before awaiting it.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so it works like tymtam already said - it looks like my problem was trying to assign end result to Func, i guess i need more sleep.

Thank you for the help tho

EDIT
I needed this:

```
Func<Task> check = async () => await _className.Method(timer);
```